# How to convert Observable to MatTableDataSource?

Tags: angular, observable

I have the code as below but have no idea on how to convert the observable "posts" from the firebase to MatTableDataSource "postsTable"?

Since I want to change the mat-table datasource to MatTableDataSource, then use the mat-paginator

I have tried to have a new MatTableDataSource in the definition or create it after the map of data returned from firestore but not working.

```
export interface Post {
    title: string;
    category: string;
    image: string;
    content: string;
    updateAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
}
export interface PostID extends Post { id: string; }

export class PostsViewComponent implements OnInit {

    private postCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection;
    posts: Observable<PostID[]>;
    postsTable = new MatTableDataSource();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.postCollection = this.angularFirestore.collection('posts');
        this.posts = this.postCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as PostID;
                data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return data;
            }))
        );
     }

}
```

Comment: return data as any;can you try this?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz of it?